# Alternatives to generic user-controls using MVVM

Tags: wpf, generics, design-patterns, mvvm, user-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define the usercontrols in mvvm pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544729/how-to-define-the-usercontrols-in-mvvm-pattern)

I'm trying to write my first WPF application using MVVM. I created a user control consisting of 2 parts, a `DataGrid` and a detail view (shows the details of the selected row in the `DataGrid`). This control is suppose to load and show different data models (like customers, products and etc.) but Since it appears to be no way to use generic user controls, I find my user control useless. and frankly I start to think any user control in MVVM pattern would be useless. Is there any alternatives for preventing unnecessary Copy/Paste of the same `DataGrid` and detail view, in my views?
thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it *is* possible to use generic user controls. But besides that, it's probably not what you want.

What you need to do is create a user control that can be re-used. There are several options:

1. Create a base user control and allow views to derive from that
2. Create a view that composes itself based on the current view model (recommended)

To create view models for a specific user control including lazy loading of view models, you can use [Catel](http://catel.codeplex.com). For more info, see [this documentation](http://catel.catenalogic.com/index.htm?gs_viewscontrols_nested_user_controls_problem.htm).

**Disclaimer:** I am one of the developers of Catel, but if other people know other ways, I am happy to hear them.

Comment: Thanks Geert. I already tried Catel and the way it uses generic user controls is amazing, but it force me to use Catel.Mvvm.IviewModel which is not compatible with my own IviewModel and the rest of my code. beside, i think you are right about that it is not what I want.
About the second option which you recommended, do you mean the View should be instantiated by getting a view model as a constructor parameter?

Comment: I was checking the second option you mentioned, and if I'm getting the idea correctly, I need to create a user control with a dependency property of the type "IViewModel" that can be set based on the current view model, then set the data bindings based on that property. however in this case only the common properties existing in IviewModel are accessable but the columns of the data-grid I mentioned, need to be bonded to a different value depending what the current view model is.

Comment: In other words, regardless of what the current view model is, there is a data-grid and some buttons and stuff that are going to use many times and make me think that i need a reusable control but on the other hand some properties like the columns need to specify exactly.

Comment: Your view needs to know when the VM is updated. Once you know this, create your own ColumnSupportedViewModelBase (implementing IColumnSupportedViewModel). Then it contains a list of columns which the view can read the IColumnSupportedViewModel.Columns to create the columns.

Then you have a user control that you can re-use with different view models.

Comment: that seems like a great solution, I'm going to give it a try, thank you so much : )